# on message error bot.on('message', async (msg) => { if (msg.author.bot) return; await msg.replay() });

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

I get this error if I type something and the bot won’t send anything.

```
(node:1596) DeprecationWarning: The message event is deprecated. Use messageCreate instead

(Use `node --trace-deprecation ...` to show where the warning was created)

file:///C:/Users/name/Desktop/Projekte/Neo%201PG/src/bot.js:9

    await msg.replay()

              ^
TypeError: msg.replay is not a function
```

**Code:**

```
import { Client, Intents } from 'discord.js';
 
export const bot = new Client({ intents: [Intents.FLAGS.GUILDS, Intents.FLAGS.GUILD_MESSAGES] });
 
bot.on('ready', () => console.log(`${bot.user.username} is online`))
bot.on('message', async (msg) => {
    if (msg.author.bot) return;
 
    await msg.replay()
});
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are 3 issues here:

- The `message` event has been deprecated since Discord.JS v13 as stated in the logs. You need to rename it to `messageCreate`.
- You misspelt `reply` as `replay`.
- The `msg.reply()` function needs a string passed as a parameter. It cannot be used with a void parameter.

Your `messageCreate` event should look like this:

```
bot.on('messageCreate', async (msg) => {
    if (msg.author.bot) return;
 
    await msg.reply('My message content!')
});
```

Comment: Thank you this is what i needed

Comment: Glad to be of help.